# Ways to check if the browser is authentic?

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, browser

I was thinking of setting up some kind of mechanism to avoid wget/cURL/etc to download, then again wget/curl can put a fake user agent so my question is more like if someone can confirm this will work

For example, the user want to download a file, at the content disposition URL I can make javascript checks (silly stuff, like send some hash using JS, return it to me then we'll see if you are an authentic browser)

If that have some cons it'll be great to know other methods

Comment: You're likely going to create headaches for your legitimate users.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you having a problem? What is it? If you have bots scraping stuff, then you could set a limit per session or IP on request per minute or hour. If the site is public, though, why care? You'll probably mess up search engines too.

Comment: @Ben: to save bandwidth, @jnpcl: could you explain a bit more why?, @jamietre well, yes the bots are scrapping so this is my attempt to save bandwidth and cost

Comment: Who are you to determine what is an *authentic* client? All that matters to you is that someone, with some client, is requesting your stuff which you have made publicly available. The nature of the *client* is not really any of your concern, what you should be concerned about is traffic and behavior per visit.

Comment: "Could an omnipotent being create a stone so heavy that even that being could not lift it?"

Comment: @slugster: I respect your opinion and all but I can't do much about it. I understand what you mean 100% but they want it that way so I can't do much about it (on their decisions). So I'm just here to assert my question, but it seems to become very controversial for some reason (maybe?)

Comment: @allensdk - you have a tough problem to fix, unfortunately focussing on the client is the wrong way to do it. Check the suggestions from @jamietre, and maybe post a question on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have a really hard time with this (if it's even possible, which I don't believe it is).

At the end of the day, the browser has to interpret your url and perform a file download. At this point, it's a standard HTTP request, which anything like wget/curl can replicate.

Comment: Thanks mate, I guess that sums it up after all

Answer (score 1):

You should use [The EFF's Panopticlick project](http://panopticlick.eff.org/) which fingerprints the http client.  This fingerprint can be compared against known web browsers.   This project also takes JavaScript and Flash into consideration.

Comment: That's a really interesting project, thanks Rook! I'll sit down soon to read their report.